# I am trying to deploy my djangorest api contactsapp to heroku

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

Iam new to python and djangorestframework.
When i run python manage.py check, i get ModuleNotFoundError  No module named 'drf-yasg'.
The fact is i already installed this module using pip install drf-yasg. I also installed it in the pipfile and Pipfile.lock file using pipenv install drf-yasg
I also added the module in the settings.py file, But still the error persists. I
[Here the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg9pI.png)

Comment: run `pip freeze`. drf-yasg is present in the output?

Comment: Yes, its present, its even present in the pipfile

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Could you please post the contents of pipfile and settings.py